# mysql ifnull and coalesce to null string seem to stringyfy numbers and they don't right align

Tags: mysql

I have a select that outputs the following column

```
| NULL |
| NULL |
| 1200 |
|   47 |
```

I want to get rid of the NULLs with blank strings. I have tried COALESCE(col, '') and IFNULL(col, ''). These then seem to stringyfy the numbers and loses the right alignment of the numbers and I get

```
|      |
|      |
| 1200 |
| 47   |
```

Obviously putting a 0 in place of the null string will preserve the col as numeric. Is there an easy way to get what I require, ie

```
|      |
|      |
| 1200 |
|   47 |
```

I know there will be a convoluted formatting way to do this but am I missing a simple trick to achieve this?

Thanks, Andy.

Comment: What is your query?

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to know what your exact concern is.

**Is it something purely visual?**

Use `LPAD()` to put some blankspaces in for the alignment.

**Is it the datatypes?**

By saying "If the field is NULL, put '' instead" you implicitly cast the column to string. If the field is a number, you would like to turn `NULL` into `0` which then leaves the column as a number. Problem is, you cannot have different datatypes per column. Either all be string, or all number, ...

Answer (score 0):

Just use `WHERE`

```
.. WHERE col IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: That will alter the resulting dataset.